# Sitecore XMC Pesonalization

Tags: sitecore, personalization

In XMC, I personalized a component using the OOTB rule

`where the cityname request parameter is equal to boston`

In Preview mode, this works fine.
When I publish and access the page after running http://localhost:3000/Page1?cityname=boston
the page always loads the default data source. The rule is never triggered.
However, if I replace this with another rule like this

`when the current day is one of Monday`

It works after I publish and run http://localhost:3000/Page1

What am I doing wrong?